# Create a new App in Facebook Developer Page for use in mobile app - Not authorized to manage apps

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an ios / android app which should share message on facebook.
It works fine when I use my personal facebook account with a testapp and facebook id for testing, but of course I can only post in my personal account.

I want to bind this app to a company account, so it post to the pinwall of the user which is currently login in the ios / android app.

But when I try to create a new app in the facebook developerpage with the company account, I only get the message: 
**"Not Authorized to Manage Apps.
This Account is not authoriized to manage apps. Please use your verified personal Facebook account to create ana manage your apps."**

Well, this is totally bullshit, because I have to bind my app to the company and not to my private account.
Why should I create an app where only I can login and which can only post in my private account ?!?

Also I was able to create an app with the company account some time ago.
Using my personal account as admin account for the company account also doesn't work because as soon as I try to access the developer page where I have to create the new app, it forces me to switch back to my private account.

I couldn't fine any information regarding this problem in 
facebook nor in the internet. Does nobody else has this problems ?!?
Besides, I also wonder why the biggest social network is so unsocial to not even offer some support email. :(

Comment: Only personal accounts can create apps